# Properties of the ring of all holomorphic modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $R$ be the ring of modular forms on congruence subgroups, say
of integral or half integral weight. In other words
$$R=\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigoplus_{k\in(1/2)\Bbb Z}M_k(\Gamma(N))\;.$$
The important property in this definition is that I require $f\in R$ to
be holomorphic on the upper-half plane and at the cusps.

As I noticed rather recently, $R$ is not a UFD, it is easy to
find examples of a form having (at least) two essentially distinct
factorizations. But in turn, this begs a number of questions concerning
this ring: for instance what are the irreducible elements, and can one
give explicitly the divisors of a given modular form.

Let me give a specific example. One can easily show that the standard
Eisenstein series $E_4$ of weight 4 and level 1 is equal to the
product of two conjugate modular forms on $\Gamma(2)$, i.e.,
$E_4=F_2\overline{F_2}$ with
$$F_2(\tau)=2E_2(\tau)-((3+\sqrt{-3})/6)E_2(\tau/2)-((3-\sqrt{-3})/6)E_2((\tau+\
1)/2)\;.$$
So two precise questions:

(1) Is $F_2$ itself a product of two modular forms, say both of weight $1$ ?
Note that the very similar form $2E_2(2\tau)-E_2(\tau)$ is indeed
such a product.

(2) Can one give the complete list of divisors of $E_4$ (of course
up to a multiplicative constant) ? Are $F_2$ and $\overline{F_2}$ the only
ones outside $1$ and $E_4$ ?

So more generally, can one characterize irreducible elements ?

Reference: [arXiv:2103.07698](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.07698)

Answer (score 3):

It may be easier to consider this question for genus zero groups, where we can construct modular forms vanishing at given points in terms of Hauptmoduln. I don't know how to find the divisors in general.

The $E_4$ series vanishes exactly at the points $M \cdot \rho$, $M \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ where $\rho = e^{2\pi i / 3}$.
Under $\Gamma(2)$, this orbit splits up into the orbits of $\rho$ and $\rho + 1$.
We have the Hauptmodul $$J_2(\tau) = \frac{\eta^8(\tau/2)}{\eta^8(2 \tau)} + 8 = q^{-1/2} + 20q^{1/2} - 62q^{3/2} \pm ...$$ whose values at $\rho$ and $\rho + 1$ are $\pm 8 \sqrt{3} i$, and the holomorphic form $$f(\tau) = \frac{\eta^8(2 \tau)}{\eta^4(\tau)}$$ of weight two which vanishes at $\infty$. By matching up the zeros and scaling appropriately, we have the factorization \begin{align*} E_4(\tau) &= f(\tau) (J_2(\tau) + 8\sqrt{3}i) \cdot f(\tau) (J_2(\tau) - 8 \sqrt{3}) \\ &= \Big( \frac{\eta^8(\tau / 2)}{\eta^4(\tau)} + 8 (1 + \sqrt{3}i) \frac{\eta^8(2 \tau)}{\eta^4(\tau)} \Big) \cdot \Big( \frac{\eta^8(\tau / 2)}{\eta^4(\tau)} + 8 (1 - \sqrt{3}i) \frac{\eta^8(2 \tau)}{\eta^4(\tau)} \Big) \\ &= F_2(\tau) \cdot \overline{F_2(\tau)}. \end{align*}

One can argue similarly in the genus zero group $\Gamma(4)$. The result is that $$E_4(\tau) = \Big( f(\tau) + \alpha_1 g(\tau) \Big) \Big( f(\tau) + \alpha_2 g(\tau) \Big) \Big( f(\tau) + \alpha_3 g(\tau) \Big) \Big( f(\tau) + \alpha_4 g(\tau) \Big),$$ where $$f(\tau) = \frac{\eta^{10}(2\tau)}{\eta^4(\tau) \eta^4(4\tau)} = \Big( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} \Big)^2 = 1 + 4q + 4q^2 + 4q^4 + ...$$ and where $$g(\tau) = 4\frac{\eta^4(4\tau)}{\eta^2(2\tau)} = \Big( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{(n+1/2)^2} \Big)^2 = 4q^{1/2} + 8q^{5/2} + 4q^{9/2} + ...$$ and where $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_4$ are the roots of $X^4 + 14X^2 + 1$.

Taking this factorization in pairs corresponds to $F_2 \cdot \overline{F_2}$ if the roots are chosen such that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 2\sqrt{3}i$ and $\alpha_3 + \alpha_4 = -2\sqrt{3}i$. So the answer to question (1) is yes. Since $f$ and $g$ are squares of theta functions, we actually get a factorization into modular forms of weight $1/2$ as well.

There is an easier factorization in level three: since $\Gamma_0(3)$ has index four and $M_1(\Gamma_0(3), \chi)$ is nonzero, the product $$\prod_{M \in \Gamma(1) / \Gamma_0(3)} f \Big|_{1, \chi} M$$ for any $f \in M_1(\Gamma_0(3), \chi)$ is a modular form of level one and weight $4$, and therefore a multiple of $E_4$. (This is an example of your observation that $R$ is not a UFD.)